# Potential workarounds for gmail blocking?

Tags: python, pandas, email, smtp, gmail

So I have a CSV file that contains about 1000 emails, names, companies, etc. Once I deploy my program, it reaches about 80 emails and then I am assuming Google is blocking me from requesting to reach its server again.

I am thinking that I set a timer, for every 70 emails, delete each in the dataframe, wait a few minutes, and redeploy starting from where it left off, because of the deleted rows. Do you think this would work? If so, how would I build a little timer like this? I can create a tracker, but how to initialize a rerun of the program?

Are there any other potential workarounds? Does it have to do with my code constantly resigning in to Google?

```
import smtplib
import pandas as pd


class Gmail(object):
    def __init__(self, email, password, recepient):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.recepient = recepient
        self.server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
        self.port = 465
        session = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.server, self.port)        
        session.ehlo
        session.login(self.email, self.password)
        self.session = session
        print('Connected to Gmail account successfully.')

    def send_message(self, subject, body):
        headers = [
            "From: " + self.email,
            "Subject: " + subject,
            "To: " + self.recepient,
            "MIME-Version: 1.0",
           "Content-Type: text/html"]
        headers = "\r\n".join(headers)
        self.session.sendmail(
            self.email,
            self.recepient,
            headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
        print('- Message has been sent.')

df = pd.read_csv('export.csv', error_bad_lines=False)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
    comp_name = (row['Account Name'])
    print('Email to: ' + comp_name)
    per_name = (row['Primary Contact: Full Name'])
    print('Email to: ' + per_name)
    rec = (row['Primary Contact Email'])
    print('Email to: ' + rec)
    message_body  = 'Hi'

    gm = Gmail('email@gmail.com', 'password', rec)
    gm.send_message('test', message_body)
    print('-- Message for ' + rec + ' (' + comp_name + ') is completed.')

print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
print('*********************************')
print('Finish reading through CSV.')
print('*********************************')
print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
```

Any thoughts would be really helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Gmail has limits applied to prevent spam.  You may find a service like MailChimp (which has a free version) better for email campaigns

Comment: Could you put the code that sends emails into a function. Then have a repeating loop which sends 70 emails and then uses the `time.sleep()` function to wait a couple minutes till the next loop occurs and sends 70 more emails.

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?hl=en suggests waiting a minimum of 1 hour after hitting the limit

Comment: It works after a minute once the program returns an error and I rerun it.

Comment: @Professor_Joykill how would I implement that?